# Semantic Ui Variables and Overrides

Tags: html, css, reactjs, less, semantic-ui

[image: React/Html Component]
[image: Inspect Element]
Hey everyone, I am using the React Semantic Ui Library and I have a question about theming.

I am using a menu collection and I want to custom 1 thing: 
in `semantic-UI/site/collections/menu.variables` I have my variable `@secondaryPointingActiveBorderColor: @black;` 
and I want to change his color if, but if I do that in this file that will be global for all menu and I want to edit the color just for one specific menu so I moved on my `menu.overrides` file but how can I select my variable with CSS? 
In my project I am using the Semantic Ui Component like this :

```
<Tab  className={styles.tab}  menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} panes={panes} />
```

In the picture, you can see the React Component and his HTML equivalent? I tried with

```
.tab.ui.pointing.secondary.menu{
    border-color:red;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by an online demo?

Comment: Something like https://codesandbox.io/s/ to reproduce the problem you are facing

Comment: I am not facing to the issue, I am just searching to the good CSS selector

Comment: Can you send "inspect element" of that element ?

Comment: @Knick I just now edited and added the capture of inspect element

Comment: I got it! Thanks, everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector was

```
.ui.secondary.pointing.menu .active.item {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class to target the required element in your case can be achieved by:

```css
.ui.secondary.pointing.menu .active.item {
  border-color: red;
}
```

But this till affect all the menu active items, so hence we need to have our own specific selecter.

So I'll be adding a class named as `stack-overflow` (change the name acc to your use case)

```
import React from "react";
import { Tab } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./style.css";

const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: "Tab 1",
    render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane>
  },
  {
    menuItem: "Tab 2",
    render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane>
  },
  {
    menuItem: "Tab 3",
    render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane>
  }
];

const TabExampleSecondaryPointing = () => (
  <Tab
    className="stack-overflow"
    menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }}
    panes={panes}
  />
);

export default TabExampleSecondaryPointing;
```

```css
// style.css
.stack-overflow .ui.secondary.pointing.menu .active.item {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Here is a sandbox for demonstration: [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-gqirl)